# Division of two statements with count returns zero

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, division

I am new to SQL (using SQLiteStudio) and am trying to work with some of the aggregate functions. I want to find the proportion of a subset of my data where mass of individuals is less than 575, but the query keeps returning zero:

```
SELECT A/B*100
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS A
    FROM Male
    WHERE mass < 575 AND location = 'Hawaii')
        ,(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS B
    FROM Male
    WHERE location = 'Hawaii')
;
```

I have read other questions where the issue was having to declare the variable in question as a decimal, but I do not know how to change the constraint of the COUNT() function. Multiplying A*B works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simplify your query to one select statement and force casting by multiplication with 100.0 where .0 should do the trick

```
SELECT
  (SUM(CASE WHEN mass < 575 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.0) / COUNT(*)
FROM Male
WHERE location = 'Hawaii'
```

Comment: That does simplify the query, but it returns 100?

Comment: Could you update your answer with results for A and B as separate statements? What values do they hold?

Comment: A is 10 and B is 34. So the correct return should 29.

Comment: I used wrong aggregate function. for the CASE statement with mass it should be `SUM`. see updated answer. If you need you can round your output or cast it to int data type to get rid of fractional part.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT A * 100 / B
```

or the intermediate result will be 0 because of integer division.

Comment: That was easy! Now I would like to do that for all locations, but I don't know how to get around the "ambiguous column name" error:

'SELECT location, A*100/B
FROM (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS A
    FROM Male M1
    WHERE mass < 575
    GROUP BY M1.location)
        ,(
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS B
    FROM Male M2
    GROUP BY m2.location)
WHERE M1.location = M2.location
GROUP BY M1.location
;'

Returns: ambiguous column name: location

Comment: SELECT M1.location

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It still returned an "ambiguous column" error, but I changed the query to incorporate a CASE WHEN statement (from the commenter above) and GROUPED BY location, and that returned what I was looking for.